# Why am I receiving a 403 when making a request to the reddit API but not in Postman?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, reddit, java-http-client

I'm trying to make a HTTP Request using Java 11 HttpClient and after receiving an access token I'm getting a 403 error.

Here's a coding snippet, after receiving a valid token:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
String endpoint = "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me/trophies";
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(endpoint))
                .header("Authorization", "bearer" + token)
                .build();
```

This produces a 403 forbidden, but doing the same request in Postman and setting the headers for Authorization as bearer + the token received results in the request passing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no whitespace to seperate the token `"bearer" + token`

Comment: Tried with whitespace and no whitespace, same results.

Comment: the must be a whitespace but its hard to tell without any further details. Maybee this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009024/reddit-api-returns-http-403